# safe-core-sdk/auth-kit giving build errors in vite

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am trying to run [safe-core-sdk/pacakages/auth-kit/example](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/7959821ab08c96cf3babb9ed906c01d644ac49f4/packages/auth-kit/example) **independently** i.e via installing @safe-global/auth-kit separatelly.

It is working fine on local developement environment. But giving **build error** on running `yarn build`

```
transforming (1) index.htmlUnexpected early exit. This happens when Promises returned by plugins cannot resolve. Unfinished hook action(s) on exit:
(vite:build-import-analysis) transform "/home/user/Frontend/example/src/main.tsx"
(commonjs--resolver) resolveId "react-dom/client" "/home/user/Frontend/example/src/main.tsx"
(vite:optimized-deps-build) load "/home/user/Frontend/example/node_modules/.vite/deps_build-dist/react-dom_client.js"
error during build:
Error: Unexpected early exit. This happens when Promises returned by plugins cannot resolve. Unfinished hook action(s) on exit:
(vite:build-import-analysis) transform "/home/user/Frontend/example/src/main.tsx"
(commonjs--resolver) resolveId "react-dom/client" "/home/user/Frontend/example/src/main.tsx"
(vite:optimized-deps-build) load "/home/amit/Frontend/example/node_modules/.vite/deps_build-dist/react-dom_client.js"
    at EventEmitter.handleEmptyEventLoop (file:///home/user/Frontend/example/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:24256:20)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:626:28)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at process.<anonymous> (file:///home/user/Frontend/example/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:24250:55)
    at process.emit (node:events:512:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the below `vite.config.ts` configuration instead the one originally created to run in the `safe-core-sdk` monorepo (You need to add `vite-plugin-node-polyfills` as a dev dependency):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), nodePolyfills()],
  server: {
    port: 3000
  }
})
```